# Discord.js invalid form body type when coding discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot using Fusion Terror's YouTube tutorial. Everything worked fine until I got an error. Here is the error that I got:

```bash
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
0.name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
```

And here is the code causing the error

```js
const clientId = "1050802610866753608";
const guildId = "1050660625472303104"
const rest = new REST({ version: "9" }).setToken(process.env.token);
    try {
      console.log("Started refreshing application (/) commands.");

      await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), {
        body: client.commandArray,
      });

      console.log("Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
```

It should have turned out like this:

```
Started refreshing application (/) commands.
Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.
Amber Heart#5868 is connected to the discord server!
```

Comment: Could you log `client.commandArray`? My first *guess* would be you did not pass the command `name:` in your slash command/s

Comment: If you are watching Fusion Terror's YouTube tutorial then go there and ask them in their Discord Server, they might have made mistake in the video which they would have corrected it in their Discord Server

btw your error is because the `client.commandArray` is wrong, there is some mistake in the slash command you created there. You can send the `client.commandArray` code here.